# How can I find all values of k which make this matrix diagonalizable over the complex field?

Tags: linear-algebra

\begin{bmatrix}
    {0} & {1} & {0}\\
    {0} & {0} & {1}\\
    {0} & {-k-9} & {k+10}
\end{bmatrix}

I have no idea how to go about this problem. I can find eigenvalues in terms of k, but I don't know how to find which k make it diagonalizable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

If it has distinct eigenvalues, it is diagonalizable, and if it doesn't, it might not be... but this amounts to only one case you need to check.

Comment: So if it doesn't have distinct eigenvalues, it could still be diagonalizable? How would that help in this case?

Comment: @Goldname Well, there's only one value of $k$ where it doesn't have distinct eigenvalues, so you just need to check if that matrix is diagonalizable.

Comment: @Goldname If the problem is that you don't know how to check if a matrix is diagonalizable, you need to check if there is only one LI eigenvector or two for that double eigenvalue.